# Which value is better to use? Boolean true or Integer 1?

Tags: c++, types, integer, boolean

Does it make any sense or not?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A boolean `true` is, well, a boolean value. Use it *whenever you want to express that a certain binary condition is met*.

The integer literal `1` is a number. Use it, whenever you are counting something.

Don't use integers for booleans and vice versa. They are different.

Consider a variable `int isEnabled`. Of course, I can guess that `0` and `1` may be the only intended values for this variable. But language-wise, nothing keeps me from assigning `4247891`. Using a boolean, however, restricts the valid values to `true` and `false`. This leaves no room for speculation.

(C++ int's and bools are somewhat convertible, but it's generally frowned upon)

Comment: Boolean is also a lot smaller in terms of memory.

Comment: Just to add reference to what Justin Satyr is saying:
Integer's are usually 4bytes (32bits) whereas Boolean's are 1byte (8bits). These are all dependant on the platform but for all of the main platforms I know this is correct. (Yes, a boolean should, in a perfect world, be 1 bit, however it's impossible to reference only one bit in memory)

Comment: @Justin Satyr A lot smaller is std::vector<bool> compared to std::vector<int> in other cases you need to take alignment into account.

Comment: Isn't std::vector<bool> secretly a bunch of bit flags though.

Answer (score 14):

I recommend using `true` if your type is logically a boolean.  This will be far more clear in terms of intent, which makes your code more maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

For what? Use a boolean for a boolean; use an integer when you're counting something.