# Why is Vulkan's VkBool32 implemented as an unsigned int?

Tags: c++, c, performance, vulkan

Looking through Sascha Willem's C++ Vulkan Demos hosted on [GitHub](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0zpi3xYHLAhUiw3IKHbqHAgIQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FSaschaWillems%2FVulkan&usg=AFQjCNEX1kb08Mz8nePZOAi-xJ7KKwiC6A&bvm=bv.114733917,d.bGQ), I noticed that some Functions returned the Datatype `VkBool32`.

I was curious to why Khronos didn't use a normal bool when I noticed the Line

`typedef uint32_t VkBool32;`

in vulkan.h. The uint32_t is defined as

`typedef unsigned int uint32_t;`

in stdint.h.

My Question is, why does it make Sense to throw away 3 Bytes if a standard Bool would do the Job with just one Byte? My little Recherche showed that there is next to no performance Difference (see [Which is faster : if (bool) or if(int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764956/which-is-faster-if-bool-or-ifint)), and Khronos themselfes said that they wanted to minimize compatibility issues (in this case old C not having a primitive boolean Type) in Order to Focus on modern Code.

(See Trevett's Quote taken from [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/03/03/here_comes_vulkan_the_next_generation_of_the_opengl_graphics_api/))

> a ground-up redesign, we’re not backwards compatible

Comment: It seems like you already answered your own question there

Comment: "Khronos themselfes said that they wanted to minimize compatibility issues (in this case old C not having a primitive boolean Type)"

Comment: "a standard Bool would do the Job with just one Byte" - unfounded assumption. You will find more than one compiler which has `sizeof(bool)==sizeof(int)`.

Comment: The linked question is x86 specific. There are still (luckily) other architectures which may yield different results and have different sizes of `bool`. The standard does not require `sizeof(bool) == sizeof(char)`. And it is unlikely that it will be a _memory_ issue at all. Also, C **does** have a boolean type (`_Bool` with `stdbool.h` providing `bool` macro).

Comment: @MSalters: "*You will find more than one compiler which has `sizeof(bool)==sizeof(int)`*" -- Example(s)? The standard doesn't say that `_Bool` is one byte, but it does have a smaller conversion rank than any other standard integer type, which *tends* to suggest it's going to be one byte. Or are you referring to some implementation-defined `bool` type rather than the standard `_Bool` type?

Comment: @Keith I meant the standard-defined `bool` instead of the implementation-defined `_Bool`, but that's what you get for tagging questions as C/C++. Anyway, see footnote 69 in the C++ standard which literally that it can be bigger.

Comment: @MSalters: Footnote 69 in which edition? A section number would be more useful. In any case, I agree that `bool`/`_Bool` *may* be bigger than 1 bytes -- but are there any compilers that actually make it bigger?

Comment: @KeithThompson: I have encountered several compilers and targets where `sizeof(bool) = sizeof(int) = 4`.  I cannot name them off the top of my head, but I could run a few experiments and get back to you.  I remember when I found out that `sizeof(bool) = 1` on x86 that it was a bit "novel".

Comment: @MSalters: `_Bool` is standard-defined, just like `bool`.  What `bool` is to C++, `_Bool` is to C.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Yes, but `_Bool` was only introduced in C99 (along with `<stdbool.h>`, which has `#define _Bool bool`). Pre-C99 code would commonly define its own `bool` type, such as `typedef int bool;` or `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`. But as the comments have now made clear, we're all talking about the built-in type `_Bool` in C or `bool` in C++.

Comment: I think if you're using something as new and shiny as Vulkan, along with it's GL3-era hardware requirements, that it's unlikely that you're stuck using C90.  Even MSVC has had `<stdbool.h>` for years now.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I've just found two myself: g++ 2.8.1 and 2.95.2 on SPARC/Solaris 9. (They're both pretty ancient, though.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try printing `sizeof(bool)` on your system.  Common answers are 4 or 1, and the value is by no means universal.  You can get different answers depending on the compiler flags you are using.

Vulkan needs to work the same way on all systems, and it needs to work correctly no matter what compiler flags you are using to compile your program.  If Vulkan was compiled with `sizeof(bool) == 1` but you compile with `sizeof(bool) == 4`, the interface will be incorrect.  I have personally witnessed this particular error happen.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but why use 3 bytes instead of 1?

Comment: @JanNilsFerner: Practically speaking, there is a lot of hardware out there where four bytes makes sense.  In order to load a single byte, you might have to load four bytes and then do the appropriate mask and shift, which is extra work.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Thanks, makes sense!